# How to create "button array" with relatively even rows and stretched buttons?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

I have an unordered list with a variable amount of items which I am treating as buttons (sort of like a navbar). I would like the "buttons" to have the following behavior:

- Have a minimum width (for the moment I have concluded that `min-width: 150px;` is a good number for my purposes).
- If the amount of "buttons" were to spill into *n* rows, I would like the arrangement of the "button" to be in *n* rows with a roughly equal number of "buttons" per row (e.g. 10 "buttons" in four rows would result in two rows having 3 "buttons" and two having only 2).
- The "buttons" should ideally stretch in width to span the full width of the container, creating a rectangle of buttons.
- The corners of the aforementioned rectangle to be rounded, so the whole setup looks like one large rounded rectangle.
- Have the "buttons" display in order.

Here is a trimmed down version of my attempt:

```css
.bar {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#foo {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#foo1 {
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#foo2 {
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#foo3 {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="foo">
    <li id="foo1" class="bar">Text</li>
    <li id="foo2" class="bar">Text</li>
    <li id="foo3" class="bar">Text</li>
</ul>
```

This fits most of the criteria, but the rounded corners are hard-coded and do not adapt well to differing amounts of "buttons" or shrinking windows (when I was creating the code snippet, the third "button" was in its own row and now it is not. Shrinking the window so the third "button" spills to its own row will yield my intended effect). It also does not "evenly" split the "buttons" amongst the rows, as if there were 8 "buttons" but room for only 7, the eighth would be alone in a second row.

Comment: Heya Feller! Your question is a bit unclear to me, but this recent pen might be of interest to you: [Codepen: Flexbox N-grid](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/gOvWZwq?editors=0100)... Check the CSS `/* mechanism */` first. Basically a `.flex-row` has a list of `[col]` (buttons in your case). It doesn't really matter whether you use an (un)ordered list or divs. It's not clear what you want with the rounded corners, adjust your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You honestly weren't too far off, just needed to shuffle the styling around some. This doesn't check every box you had, e.g.

> If the amount of "buttons" were to spill into n rows, I would like the arrangement of the "button" to be in n rows with a roughly equal number of "buttons" per row (e.g. 10 "buttons" in four rows would result in two rows having 3 "buttons" and two having only 2).

this is absolutely doable, but would require some javascript to implement as well as using grid instead so you can have finer control over rows and columns.

```css
/*
  - Removed padding on list
  - simplified flex value for items
  - Removed borders from items
  - Removed border radius from items
  - Added background colors to items & list
  - Added border to list
  - Added gap to list to give the appearance of internal borders
  - Added border Radius & overflow: hidden; to list, rounding outer corners
*/

.bar {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

#foo {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  gap: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul id="foo">
  <li class="bar">Text</li>
  <li class="bar">Text</li>
  <li class="bar">Text</li>
  <li class="bar">Text</li>
  <li class="bar">Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the response! It worked like a dream! One quick question about the missing requirement:
"this is absolutely doable, but would require some javascript to implement as well as using grid instead so you can have finer control over rows and columns."
I'm not too familiar with grid. Can you have it so elements in one row have one width, and elements in a different row have a different width? I thought this was the advantage of flexbox.

Comment: @SomeRandomFellow, You're right in that being the advantage of flex-box, but if the goal is to have an even amount of items per row you need to be able to specify which row the items sit in, which is grids strength and that's why you'd need to use javascript to get it to behave how you want it to - grid lets you dictate how many columns or rows an item takes up, so if you wanted the max items per row to be 3, if you set the grid to be 6 even columns, you can apply a class that changes how many columns each item spans - so for 3 items in a row, they'd span 2 columns each, 2 items spans 3, etc..